# How to do this query (az --query "custom-headers host")

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-traffic-manager, azure-cli2

I can't just print the (value) information.

```
],
"id": "/subscriptions/x/resourceGroups/x/providers/Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/x",
"location": "global",
"maxReturn": null,
"monitorConfig": {
  "customHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "host",
      "value": "site.company.com"
    }
  ],
```

az network traffic-manager profile list -g X --output table --query "[].{Traffic:name, URL:id.monitorConfig.customHeaders.value}"

Comment: Hello @Sandrix, welcome to stackoverflow, You want to print out the content of the value key ? in the case you want to get ite.company.com ? please state clearly what you want.

Comment: Hi, I want to print only the columns with the (name of traffic manager) that this already works. And also beside this value (site.company.com). 

My command "-query [].{Name:name, ?:?}"

I don't know how to build this condition to redeem the value of (site.company.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the traffic manager name, customer headers values using the below Azure CLI query in Json format:

```
az network traffic-manager profile list --resource-group stacklogictest  --query "[].{name:name,url:monitorConfig.customHeaders[].value}"  --output json
```

[image]